# Seasonal Hours using PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to create a PHP script that will show the seasonal hours of "Saturday 9am - 3pm" but only April 25 thru September 25 and my attempt is not working:

```
$day = date("d");
$month = date("m");

//default:
$sathours = "Sat by appt only";

//Premise: Appt only 04/25 thru 09/25

if($day >= 25 && $month >= 09 && $month <= 04) { 
$sathours = 'Sat by appt only. <br />Please call.';
} else {
$sathours = 'Sat 9am-3pm';
}

echo "$sathours";
```

As a non-programmer, I think I've looked at this too much and can't see where I've gone astray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects as they are comparable (and much more readable)

```
$today   = new DateTime();
$april25 = new DateTime('April 25th');
$sept25  = new DateTime('September 25th');

//Premise: Appt only 04/25 thru 09/25
$sathours = 'Sat by appt only. <br />Please call.';
if($today >= $april25 && $today <= $sept25) { 
    $sathours = 'Sat 9am-3pm';
}

echo $sathours;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/319035)

Comment: I agree with the date time usage is a cleaner approach. This doesn't work though for dates past the sept 25 date because of the $now variable.

Comment: @jhansen That was fixed ten minutes ago

Comment: @jhansen That's very likely. Good job paying attention, though. :)